# numpy.mean gives different values when matplotlib.pyplot is imported

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am having an issue that I really can not figure out (honestly I don't even know where to start).

I have a data set for which I calculate the mean using numpy, after which I need to plot a histogram using pyplot.  The issue is that after importing matplotlib.pyplot the mean changes each time I run the script.  If I comment out the "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" line everything works fine though.  Here is my code if you need to see it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### READ DATA ###
table = []
with open ('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        table.append(row)
f.close()

names = table[0]
data = np.array(table)

ind = 0
for n in names:
    if(n == "dataset8"):
        dataset8 = np.array(data[1:, ind], "int32")

    if (n == "dataset10"):
        dataset10 = np.array(data[1:,ind], "int32")

    ind += 1


### GET MEAN VALUE of datasets ###
print "avg dataset8  = " + str(np.mean(dataset8))
print "avg dataset10 = " + str(np.mean(dataset10))
```

np.mean(dataset8) is the value that changes every time I run the script (only when "import matplotlib.pyplot" is included), while np.mean(dataset10) works fine.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Tom

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is now, your problem cannot be reproduced, because we do not have the input data. However, it is also not feasible to post here a huge dataset, so maybe you could see if you can reproduce your problem with a small set of test data.